# Converting .py to .exe with a GUI frontend

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert **.py** to **.exe** , but I'm not able to convert it with the help of py2exe in the command line.

I searched on the internet about a **py2exe with a GUI frontend** and I got the results as:

**GUI2EXE** (3/5) (The best one I found, but the .exe comes with lots of .dll files and the .exe file is buggy and doesn't work properly.)

**H-two-O** (2/5) (Waste of time. Doesn't compile any .exe files associated with Tkinter. Very creative and useful for other file formats.)

**PytoEXE** (1.3/5) (Just as H-two-O , but doesn't compile Tkinter files to .exe)

**GP2EXE** (?/5) (I didn't try it out. Maybe you can give a view on it.)

**PyBuilder** (2.7/5) (Reliable, good GUI interface with options but lacks some of the features and compiling speed to that of GUI2EXE.)

**PythontoEXE** (1.3/5) (Same as PytoEXE)

But these **weren't good**. I need a compiler better than all of the compilers listed above which can compile Tkinter files to .exe without any bugs.

Comment: Yep, you'll have to learn how to use it. You should ask a question about how to use py2exe rather than look for alternatives.

Comment: I've tried py2exe on the command line but it's a nuisance.

Comment: How exactly? I have a feeling that you want to avoid the shell, but you better learn it. It's really useful. Otherwise, you *could* use cxFreeze.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I use `py2exe`. I know this isn't what you're asking for, but according to my experience, it's really annoying until it works. So please hear me out.

Assuming your Python file is called `main.py`.

New file `setup.py` (same folder):

```py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['main.py'])
```

From here, you can create a `.bat` file in the same folder, or run it from the command line. Either way, you'll be running `python setup.py py2exe` to compile the code.